# FIR for damaged Indian passport?

Tags: passports, india

I have an Indian passport.

Do I need to file a first information report (FIR) at the police station if my passport is only damaged (not stolen)?

Only the outer cover has been a little bit detached, but all pages and the photo are intact, so I think it comes under category (1) of damaged passports.

The passport website considers damaged and lost passports in a single category, so I am confused.

Any proper response is really appreciated.

Edit: I have received the Passport without FIR being registered.

Comment: Did you fill the Annexure F form or that wasn't necessary either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, You don't need to file an FIR in case of damaged passport.
You will just have to apply for the new passport(reissue) and attach your old passport with the application.

The [Indian Government website](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports) clearly states:

> In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis.

The FIR is only required for the lost passports.

> Loss of passport should be immediately reported to the nearest Police Station and to the Passport Office (PO) or Indian Mission, if abroad.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have got new passport, without being need to apply for FIR.