# Visa stamp damaged in torn passport?

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, passport-stamps

I recently got a Schengen visa. Have to fly in a week’s time from today. Situation is — my passport is torn and visa stamp is completely damaged. I’m from India and travelling to Europe. What can be done?

Comment: What is the overall extent of the damage to your passport? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122673/fir-for-damaged-indian-passport?r=SearchResults

Comment: Only 4-5 pages have been impacted. Rest everything is good.

Answer (score 1):

With the damaged visa stamp and passport, there is a good possibility that you are going to be denied boarding. You have to apply for replacement passport. The ID pages being normal is not enough. Even if its 3-4 pages, they will deny boarding.

I have been in a situation where some pages got damaged because of water and ink got spread for passport stamps. Even though ID pages are not damaged (due to plastic lamination), I was not allowed to board without signing extensive waivers. My visa was on a separate card, which was unaffected.

After getting replacement passport, you have to contact VFS for getting a replacement of damaged visa (probably won't have to do all over again, just getting stamp on new passport) in your new passport.

Its highly unlikely to get it all done within a week. Your best bet is to apply for tatkal replacement of passport and rush for replacement stamp.

Answer (score 1):

A Torn passport is never a good thing when travelling.

Depending on the extent of the damage - your problem might be the **passport** and not only the **visa** because the passport itself can be deemed invalid and at worse case and can cause you all sorts of delays and uncomfortable situations while travelling Starting from denied boarding and all the way to denied entry and even detention.

Of course - this no one can tell you without seeing the actual damage.

In general - If the visa itself is not damaged - you can issue a new passport and travel with both old passport and new as the general rule is :

> Valid visas in full, invalidated travel documents are accepted
>   provided accompanied by a new travel document.

The above,again - will depend on the extent of the damage and the "Invalidation" reason.

Many types of damages can be inflicted on a passport / visa for example is the machine code intact ? The personal image ?  Readable or not ..

If the itself visa is damaged - ( and in my opinion in any case ) ***you better contact the issuing consulate and have them assess the situation and further guide you*** - and in any case it would be better to be issued a new one if possible.

That again - because without seeing the extent of the damage, no one can really tell you otherwise, or take any responsibility for it and the best authority to answer this in this case will be the issuing consulate.

All the above takes takes even more effect when you state that the visa "*is completely damaged*"